# Assignment in strings

Tags: c++, string

I'm having trouble understanding some particular behaviour of assignment in strings.

```
//method 1
std::string s;
s+='a' //This works perfectly
```

but

```
//method2
std::string s;
s="" + 'a';//This gives unexpected value
```

Why 2nd method gives unexpected value ? From what I've read string default constructor initialise string variable as empty string, if no constructor is specified. `And s+='a'` should be same as `s=s+a`. So why isn't the method 2 same as method 1?

And one more query on the same topic , if we can't initialise a string with char literal then how can we assign a char literal to it?

```
std::string s2='a'//gives error while compiling
```

whereas

```
std::string s2;
s2='a'//works perfect
```

From what I understand is we cannot initialise a string variable by char variable because string constructor needs argument of the type`(const char *)`. Why is there not any such restriction while assigning?

Comment: `"foo"` is not a `std::string`, it is a *string literal*, which is an array of `char`, more-or-less a `char const*`. If you want to do `std::string` type operations on it, you have to turn it into one first: `std::string("foo")`.

Comment: BoBTFish is right, try `std::string("") + 'a'`

Comment: Increase the warning Level. I bet you get warnings.

Comment: Or, if you know about *user-defined literals*, `using namespace std::string_literals; "foo"s` + ....

Comment: @BoBTFish I think now i understand my mistake , thanks for the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first query ,

method 1 works perfectly cause in this method you are adding string object type and char literal .
and `s+='a'` , is indeed same as `s=s+'a'`

focus on the fact that s is string object type rather than string literal.

In the 2nd method , you are adding string literal 
and char literal . Focus on the difference between the two , In first method there is string object you can add string or char literals to string object type,its one of the features provided by string object type . But you cant add simply add the literals with each other.In c++ , however "StringLiteral1" "StringLiteral2" , will result in the concatenation of the two string literals.

for 2nd query,

Initialisation is not the same as assignment , string object default constructor takes `const char *` to initialise . Assignment is a completely differenet story(if not,someone please do correct me ).

Comment: *"default constructor takes `const char *`"*

Comment: Well, it isn't a *default* constructor if it takes an argument. It's just one of the non-default constructors.

Answer (score 2):

`""` is a string literal of type `const char[]`, and you are adding the string literal, i.e. the pointer to the first element, `'\0'`, to another character. This will naturally give you something else then you expected.

If you want it to be the same as `s += 'a'`, you'll need to use a `std::string` literal: `s += ""s + 'a';`. This works, as `""s` is an empty `std::string`, and you just add another character to it.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `s="" + 'a';` Remember that `""` is not a `std::string` but a `const char*`. And `const char*` doesn't have a predefined concatenation operator. That's why you are having an unexpected behavior instead of concatenation.

Comment: _"And const char* doesn't have a predefined + operator."_ It has. Ever heard about pointer aritmethics?

Comment: The OP said that `"" + `` a`" dose not give an error but unexpected results.

Comment: It's still not an *error", but unexpected behaviour.  If you write `"abcd" + 2`, you return a pointer to the "c" in the string.  If you add 5, you obtain a pointer just after the trailing '\0'.  If you add anything greater than 5, you obtain an invalid pointer (I can't remember if the addition is undefined behaviour, or if just *using* the pointer is UB).  'a' almost certainly has a value of 97, and adding that to a pointer to a single null character probably ends up pointing at random memory.